# Data is there, but count returns 0

Tags: sql, scala, csv, apache-spark

CSV SAMPLE:  EMPLOYEE.CSV :

```
emp_name,emp_badge,door_number,date_time,usage_type
Jean-Paul Ranu,24441foobar,5,22:36:27,ENTRANCE
Raoul Raoul,7555foobar,5,01:08:49,ENTRANCE
Henri Papier,66686foobar,4,03:13:16,ENTRANCE
Gilles Fernandez,36664foobar,3,20:55:11,ENTRANCE
Jean Bono,27775foobar,4,18:45:42,EXIT
Laure Eal,53450foobar,1,13:42:12,ENTRANCE
```

---

SPARK-SCALA CODE :

```
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object MonObjet {
    def main(args:Array[String]){
        val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder
          .master("local")
          .appName("monTruc")
          .getOrCreate
        val conf = new SparkConf()
          .setMaster("local")
          .setAppName("myApp")
          .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")

        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema","true").option("sep",",").load("C:/Users/Houssemus/Desktop/emp_data.csv")
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")
        val req=spark.sql("SELECT  COUNT(emp_name)  FROM employee ").show()
        // df.show()
    }
}
```

I imported a csv file which I created with python in order to preprocess in spark with scala . after importing it , i can visualize the data , but once i query it , it returns zero .[image]

Comment: if I do : spark.sql("select * from employee").show() , then it works and returns the data , but once i use sthg else , it returns nothing , why ?

Comment: To prevent misunderstandings: Do you want to get the number of rows which contains a value?

Comment: I want to get the most used door number as a matter of fact ... but count() doesnt work in the first place , it returns 0 .

Comment: Are you running this code from local or cluster?

Comment: im running it locally

Comment: if I want to know the most used door  for entrance , what would be the sql query to do that with spark pleasse ? and thanks everyone ! @Lamanus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the recent version of spark, you don't need to define the spark context as you defined `sc`. So, after you build the spark session, you defined the spark context again which cause some miss-configuration. Delete the code `val sc` definition would work.

As your second question, try the below code.

```
val req = spark.sql("""
SELECT door_number, 
       Count(door_number) AS count 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  usage_type = 'ENTRANCE' 
GROUP  BY door_number 
ORDER  BY count DESC 
""").show()
```

It will give the result like this.

```
+-----------+-----+
|door_number|count|
+-----------+-----+
|          5|    2|
|          3|    1|
|          1|    1|
|          4|    1|
+-----------+-----+
```